# Применение маски к box-shadow

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-mask

У меня есть div с примененной к нему маской. Я заметил, что я не могу применить `box-shadow` к тому же самому div, поэтому я должен переместить тень на `wrapper` div.

Проблема в том, что если тень помещается на div тени, маска не применяется к тени.

Как я могу применить маску к div и его тени?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 17px 13px 7px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;


  
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(
    circle at center top,
    transparent 30px,
    black 31px
  ) top / 100% 51%, 
  radial-gradient(
    circle at right bottom,
    transparent 30px,
    black 31px
  ) right bottom / 51% 51%, 
  radial-gradient(
    circle at left bottom,
    transparent 30px,
    black 31px
  ) left bottom / 51% 51%;
  
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Applying mask to box-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64650585/7394871) от участника  [@alexandernst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940158/alexandernst).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64650585/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна `drop-shadow`, а не тень `box-shadow:`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  filter:drop-shadow(17px 13px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75));
}

.b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;


  
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(
    circle at center top,
    transparent 30px,
    black 31px
  ) top / 100% 51%, 
  radial-gradient(
    circle at right bottom,
    transparent 30px,
    black 31px
  ) right bottom / 51% 51%, 
  radial-gradient(
    circle at left bottom,
    transparent 30px,
    black 31px
  ) left bottom / 51% 51%;
  
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64652615/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>